# Como que eu coloco mais de um filtro em minha busca de um get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Estou usando mongodb e node. No codigo abaixo estou buscando apenas por um codigo de 8 digitos, mas queria colocar tb uma busca por nome, como eu faço?

```
exports.getByCode = (req, res, next) => {
    Roles
        .findOne({
            codigo: req.params.codigo,
            active: true
        }, '_id title price address date hora createBy minuto alcohol tags')
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'Listagem de roles especificos por user feita com sucesso',
                statusCode: 200,
                body: data,
            })
        }).catch(e => {
            res.status(400).send({
                statusCode: 400,
                message: 'Falha ao cadastrar o role',
                error: e
            });
        });
},
```

Comment: voce tentou usar `query`? Se estiver usando express, voce pode usar `req.query`  para trazer mais de um parametro atraves da url. Veja aqui =>  https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req.query

Comment: faz algo assim antes para ver se está pegando o codio const {codigo} = req.params.codigo e depois roda console.log(codigo) é um pouco estranho esse parâmetro código, edite sua pergunta e coloque a rota e a schema referente as Regras.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, ao se fazer uma api `request` com mais de um filtro uma boa pratica é utilizar `queryParams` ao invés de `pathParams` como esta sendo utilizado no exemplo.

Dessa maneira você pode ter quantos filtros forem necessários no object req.

Ex de uma possivel solução, supondo `http://sua_url/end_point?codigo=12345789&nome=Jhon`:

```html
exports.getByCode = (req, res, next) => {
    const { codigo, nome } = req.query
    Roles
        .findOne({
            codigo, 
            nome,
            active: true
        }, '_id title price address date hora createBy minuto alcohol tags')
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: 'Listagem de roles especificos por user feita com sucesso',
                statusCode: 200,
                body: data,
            })
        }).catch(e => {
            res.status(400).send({
                statusCode: 400,
                message: 'Falha ao cadastrar o role',
                error: e
            });
        });
}
```